# The test results are not getting ingested into Elastic search from Jmeter backend listener

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, kibana

There is set of Original scripts of Jmeter which ingests the test results into Elastic search, which can be visualized using Kibana dashboard. Whereas, if I try to duplicate the original Jmeter scripts and modifying a little won't ingest the data into Elastic search, Hence the real time data is not displayed on Kibana dashboard. The Kibana backend listener configuration is kept same as the Original script.

I tried to create a trivial test plan and added same Backend listener configurations as we have in the original scripts. Yet no luck on this.
I'm expecting the test results data gets ingested into Elastic search index and able to display real time data on Kibana dashboard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When JMeter doesn't behave as expected get used to check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.

It also makes sense to [increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the components you're using

In general your question cannot be comprehensively answered in its current form, it's better to come up with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for example using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 0):

Update the Jmeter backend listener version to 2.7.1 and
select this option in the backend listener:
`io.github.delirius325.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchBackendClient`